# ScrollBehavior doesn't work properly in nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I have created a file app/router.scrollBehavior.js for scroll position, but when I press browser back button, savedPosition doesn't call because fetch api has not completed. Can any one help me for this. How to know when api's completion done after my savePosition trigger otherwise every time scroll got on bottom position. is ther any way to get store, commit fetch hooks in same functions.
`export default function (to, from, savedPosition) { if (savedPosition) { return savedPosition } else { return { x: 0, y: 0 } } }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async` scrolling, that resolves to the desired position descriptor.
It's possible to hook this up with events from a page-level transition component to make the scroll behavior play nicely with your page transitions.

```
scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({ x: 0, y: 0 })
    }, 500)
  })
}
```